# Why my program doesn't execute if else correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am testing on three different conditions;
First one is the selectedIndex of the DropDown1 is 2 and the TextBox is empty
Second is the selectedIndex of the DropDown1 is 2 and the TextBox is not empty
Last one is the selectedIndex of the dropDown is 3
When executing It goes directly to the Last condition and doesnt even test the first ones.

```
protected void btnValider_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDown1.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {

        if (txtNvSt.Text != null)
        {

            con.charger("update Reparation set dateReception='" + txtDateReception.Text + "', nNouvST='" + txtNvSt.Text + "', suivieMateriel='" + txtSuivi.Text + "', statut='" + cmbStatut.SelectedValue + "' where serviceTag ='" + txtServiceTag.Text + "'", false);
            con.charger("update Materiel set reparation= NULL where serviceTag='" + txtServiceTag.Text + "'", false);
            Session["ST"] = txtNvSt.Text;
            Response.Redirect("NouveauMAt.aspx");

        }
        else
            if (txtNvSt.Text == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("txtNv null");
                con.charger("update Reparation set dateReception='" + txtDateReception.Text + "',suivieMateriel='" + txtSuivi.Text + "',statut='" + DropDown1.SelectedValue + "'  where serviceTag ='" + txtServiceTag.Text + "'", false);
                con.charger("update Materiel set reparation = NULL where serviceTag='" + txtServiceTag.Text + "'", false);
                con.charger("insert into Stocker values('1', '" + txtServiceTag.Text + "')", false);

            }
    }
    else
    {

        con.charger("update Materiel set reparation = NULL, idEmplacement = NULL where serviceTag='" + txtServiceTag.Text + "'", false);
        con.charger("insert into Stocker values('4', '" + txtServiceTag.Text + "')", false);
        con.charger("update Reparation set dateReception='" + txtDateReception.Text + "',suivieMateriel='" + txtSuivi.Text + "',statut='" + cmbStatut.SelectedValue + "' where serviceTag='" + txtServiceTag.Text + "'", false);
        Response.Redirect("StockHS.aspx");
    }


}
```

Comment: Debug your code and see what values of each property checked in conditions. If you want answer on SO please make sure to provide sample that does not require external information (like what is `cmbStatut`) OR provide values (as inline comments) for each property used in the code.

Comment: `cmbStatut.SelectedIndex` is not equal to `2`. If you debug you can see this for yourself.

Comment: Set a `breakpoint` on the first `IF` statement and debug yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The `Text` property of an ASP TextBox is *never* null. [See the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The default value is an empty string so if you want to check if the textbox is actually empty, change your condition to something like this:

```
if (txtNvSt.Text != string.Empty)
```

Alternatively you can use [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which accounts for whitespace which, depending on your situation, is probably still considered "empty".

You're saying this just goes directly to the `else` (I think). You say that the condition is the following:

> Last one is the selectedIndex of the dropDown is 3

However, your `else` doesn't actually check anything. If the first case fails, which checks `DropDown1.SelectedIndex == 2`, then you will *always* enter this `else` no matter what the value of `SelectedIndex` is.

Keep in mind that `SelectedIndex` is **zero based** so the 2nd item in the list is index `1` and so on.

Comment: better to use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`